# Oracle's collate clause not working

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I've tried using a query with the COLLATE clause, but I'm getting an ORA-00933.

```
SELECT *
 FROM t1
 WHERE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci = k;
```

link to the doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/charset-collate.html

Do I need to install something first ?

Comment: You need to read the correct manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2065646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link is from the MySQL Reference Manual.  MySQL happens to be owned by Oracle Corporation which is why the documentation is available on an oracle.com link.  But it is a completely different product from Oracle the database that is owned by Oracle Corporation.  (Just for added fun, Oracle Corporation also owns a few other database products like RDB that are also completely different from the Oracle database).

Assuming that you are using Oracle and not MySQL, what is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh my bad. I'm trying to do some fulltext search. So I need to remove accents in the where condition. For example the value čťžý to ctzy.